# How to extract chunks of a 2D numpy array that has been flattened

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing, jax, pde

I would like to know the best way of extacting chunks of elements from a 2D numpy array that has been flattened. See example python code below which hopefully explains what I want to do a little better.

```py
import numpy as np

nx = 5
nz = 7
numGPs = nx*nz

GPs_matrix = np.arange(numGPs).reshape((nx,nz), order='F')
av = np.zeros_like(GPs_matrix)
av[1:-1,1:-1] = (GPs_matrix[1:-1,2:] + GPs_matrix[1:-1,:-2] + GPs_matrix[2:,1:-1] + GPs_matrix[:-2,1:-1])/4
# How to do the above if GPs is flattened as per below?
GPs_flat = GPs_matrix.reshape(-1, order='F')
# One (very clunky) way is to do the following
cor = GPs_matrix[1:-1,1:-1].reshape(-1, order='F')
btm = GPs_matrix[1:-1,:-2].reshape(-1, order='F')
top = GPs_matrix[1:-1,2:].reshape(-1, order='F')
lft = GPs_matrix[:-2,1:-1].reshape(-1, order='F')
rgt = GPs_matrix[2:,1:-1].reshape(-1, order='F')
av_flat = np.zeros_like(GPs_flat)
av_flat[cor] = (GPs_flat[top] + GPs_flat[btm] + GPs_flat[rgt] + GPs_flat[lft])/4
# Check
print(av.reshape(-1, order='F'))
print(av_flat)
# Is there a better way?
# I see np.r_() may be useful but I don't know how to best use it. I assume the below attempt can be improved upon
sl_cor = np.r_[nx+1:2*nx-1,2*nx+1:3*nx-1,3*nx+1:4*nx-1,4*nx+1:5*nx-1,5*nx+1:6*nx-1] # Should match cor above
# Check
print(sl_cor)
print(cor)
# The below also works but I would like to avoid using loops if possible
print(np.r_[*[np.arange(1,nx-1)+nx*j for j in range(1,nz-1)]])
```

Essentially, I am trying to solve the possion equation in two spatial dimensions. It is convenient to set up the problem in the form of a 2D array as the location of the elements in the array corresponds to the position of the grid points in the cartesian mesh. Ultimately I will be using an iterate solver in jax to solve the linear system (e.g. bicgstab) which requires a linear operator function as input. Therefore, the function needs to return a vector and loops are not efficient.

Comment: Is there a problem with reshaping to `(nx,ny)`, extracting the values, and then returning the flattened result?

Comment: What do you mean by chunks? what do they represent in the GPS matrix?

Comment: This seems like an XY problem.  There's no  need to do the convolution on the flattened arrays when they can be easily converted (post- or pre- calculation) into 2D arrays that can be easily convolved (and please, use `scipy.signal.convolve` or some other convolution tool for this instead of making 4 temporary arrays)

Comment: Thanks for your comments everyone. Sorry for taking so long to respond. jared, no problem with adopting your suggestion, I had initially assumed this way might be slightly less efficient (re-shaping and then flattening every iteration), but will roll with it as it seems to be the consensus. Daniel F, thanks for your suggestion, convolve did the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it looks like what you're attempting to compute is a convolution. In general I'd avoid doing a convolution by hand, and instead use something like `scipy.signal.convolve2d`. Here's the equivalent for your case:

```py
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
kernel = np.array(([[0, 1, 0],
                    [1, 0, 1],
                    [0, 1, 0]])) / 4
av = np.zeros_like(GPs_matrix)
av[1:-1, 1:-1] = convolve2d(GPs_matrix, kernel, mode='valid').astype(av.dtype)
```

In the flattened case, your best approach is probably going to be to reshape the 1D input, perform the 2D convolution, and then flatten the output. For example:

```py
def eval_1D(vec):
  mat = vec.reshape(nx, nz, order='F')
  kernel = np.array(([[0, 1, 0],
                      [1, 0, 1],
                      [0, 1, 0]])) / 4
  av = np.zeros_like(mat)
  av[1:-1, 1:-1] = convolve2d(mat, kernel, mode='valid').astype(av.dtype)
  return av.ravel(order='F')

print(eval_1D(GPs_matrix.ravel(order='F')))
# [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  6  7  8  0  0 11 12 13  0  0 16 17
#  18  0  0 21 22 23  0  0 26 27 28  0  0  0  0  0  0]
```

Comment: Thanks very much @jakevdp. This has worked a treat. Sorry for taking so long to respond.

Comment: Actually, one follow-up question @jakevdp, why is it advisable to use convole2d rather than slicing methods for this problem?

Comment: Convolution lowers to a single `conv_general` operation that can often be executed more efficiently than when the same operation is expressed as a sequence of indexing operations.